# LINQtoSQL and Serialization

Tags: asp.net, linq-to-sql, data-access

I am a newbie to LINQtoSQL. I opted to learn it because I didn't have much experience writing stored Procedures in SQL and thought that LINQtoSQL might be an alternative way to do data access. Anyway, I created a simple ASP.NET application with a couple of simple web forms that collect some data from the user.

Next I added a LINQtoSQL Data object (a dbml file) to my project. Connected it to a DataSource in my SQL database and allowed the OR/Designer to do it' magic about creating an entity for me. All seemed too good to be true. Until, I got to the saving the data that I have collected in my web forms back to the database. That is where I began to learn about the serialization problems with LINQtoSQL.

Specifics are that my web forms collect data in multiple steps. Like any ASP developer, I store this data in the ViewState as I go through Page LifeCycles. Finally, once my ViewState has all the data that is required, hit the submit button to send it to the database using LINQtoSQL entity object. And this is where I start getting serialization exception:

System.Runtime.Serialization.SerializationException: Type 'System.Data.Linq.ChangeTracker+StandardChangeTracker' in Assembly 'System.Data.Linq, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089' is not marked as serializable.

I looked around on the web. I know that my one and only LINQtoSQL entity (that I am assigning from my ViewState) is seiralizable since is it decorated with required DataContract and DataMember attributes. After much reading I tried a solution given by Brain Orrell at the following link that calls for providing your own serializer. It seems very complicated for what I am trying to achieve (a simple write of a piece of data to a database) and the serialization exceptions still didn't go away. Although, strangely, my entity is correctly written to the database now:

http://borrell.parivedasolutions.com/2008/02/linq-to-sql-updating-in-aspnet-right.html

My question is, what is correct and a simple way to pass the ViewState data to a LINQtoSQL entity so it could be written to the database. And if some one knows of a specific but good example to follow, I will appreciate it. Otherwise I can post code from my own project and we can go from there.

Thanks if advance.

Fike

Comment: `[DataContract]` != `[Serializable]`  (to be more precise, something that is marked with only `[Serializable]` *can* be handled by `DataContractSerializer` but something that is marked with only `[DataContract]` is not handled by `[Serializable]` serializers (like `BinaryFormatter`).)

Answer (score 0):

Kirk's comment is in fact answer to your question. I just give you one more suggestion - if you are "tabula rasa" in ORMs, quickly forget about unpleasant experience with LinqToSql and try new Entity Framework. It is much more robust,flexible solution (with the similar visual designer and "magic" around it), but it allows you to use POCOs as your entity classes - you can make it serializable, or tweak it in any other way needed.